# CLion WSL Debugging is not working on Windows 10

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, clion

[image]

[image]

[image]

I can execute my project on WSL(Ubuntu 22.04 LTS) but I can't debug my project. CLion is installed on Windows 10.

Error message is as below.

```
com.jetbrains.cidr.execution.debugger.backend.gdb.GDBDriver$GDBCommandException: Warning:
Cannot insert breakpoint 3.
Cannot access memory at address 0x806be6e

Process finished with exit code -1
```

I'm looking forward your wise answer.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you wsl version 1 or 2? I am having the same problem with wsl 1 as you. I solved this problem by upgrading wsl to wsl 2.

To see whether your Linux distribution is set to WSL 1 or WSL 2, use the command: `wsl -l -v`.
To change versions, use the command: `wsl --set-version <distro name> 2` replacing  with the name of the Linux distribution that you want to update. For example, `wsl --set-version Ubuntu-20.04 2` will set your Ubuntu 20.04 distribution to use WSL 2.

If an error occurs during the upgrade process, refer to Microsoft's official documentation. [Here's the link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-manual)

Answer (score 0):

The warning message

```
Cannot insert breakpoint 3.
Cannot access memory at address 0x806be6e
```

is directly coming from gdb, instead of CLion. Although I consider they could have pointed this out clearly.

While this gdb problem refers to a known and open issue of WSL: [[WSL1] Cannot debug anything after upgrading to 22.04](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/8356)

I excerpt the brief description of this problem as follows:

> The real reason for this issue is that WSL1 lacks /proc/*/mem files, and old version gdb will fallback to use ptrace when it fails to read /proc//mem.
> But after Jul 2021, Gdb disables such fallback and always assumes /proc//mem is available, so gdb on Ubuntu 22.04 cannot access memory under WSL1.

A simple solution is:

Just download the [GDB 13.2 tarball](https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gdb/gdb-13.2.tar.gz), build it, and replaced the old gdb in your system.

```
> ./configure && make && make install
```